# How to show that a function is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

Let $u \in W^{s,p}$(the space $W^{s,p}$ is the frational sobolev space), $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $\varepsilon>0$. The function $f$ is defined by
$$H_{\varepsilon}(u-\mu) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \quad \mbox{if }\ u > \mu + \varepsilon, \\[0.1cm]
   \frac{u-\mu}{\varepsilon -\mu} & \quad \mbox{if }\ \mu \leq u\leq \mu + \varepsilon,\\[0.1cm]
   0 & \quad \mbox{if }\ u < \mu,
  \end{array}
  \right.$$
Is this function continuous? and if yes how to prove it?

Comment: At no point have you defined $f$... Also where lies $s$?